# Create an array with elements of different types

Tags: c

I need to declare an array that consists of different variable types, mainly:

```
char *A; uint32_t B; int C;
```

As I understood in the tutorials, in the array you declare the type and the number of element. So to say something like:

```
int a[3];
```

where in this case, the type of the three elements are all integers. 
So how do I want to declare an array that consists of the three different types mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of an array in C is a collection of elements of the SAME type. What you are looking for is probably a `struct`.

```
struct s
{
    char* A;
    uint32_t B;
    int C;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct s test;
    test.A = "Hello";
    test.B = 12345;
    test.C = -2;

    // Do stuff with 'test'
    return 0;
}
```

Or, as mentioned in a comment below, you could use a `union` instead. But then you can't use A, B, and C at the same time like I have in the example above - only one of them will be stored - in my example it would be C.

You can make an array of structures if you need to.

```
struct s test[5];  // Array of structures
```

Comment: the problem is : I need to put my struct members inside one array, and do something with this array variable. so it is not possible per definition?

Comment: And notice you can have an array of `struct`s, ie in `struct whatever array[100]`, the `array` has 100 elements, all of type `struct whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `union`

i.e.

```
typedef struct {
        int type;
        union {

        char *A;
        uint32_t B;
        int C; 
        }} item;
```