# Create array with elements of different type in Fortran

Tags: arrays, struct, fortran

Exactly the same questions as [Create an array with elements of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646297/create-an-array-with-elements-of-different-types), except how to do this in Fortran?

Say I want an array with the first dimension an `integer` type, the second `real` and the third `character` (string) type. Is it possible to create a "`struct`" in Fortran too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example program of a derived type use:

```
TYPE mytype
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(3)   :: ints
  REAL,DIMENSION(5)      :: floats
  CHARACTER,DIMENSION(3) :: chars
ENDTYPE mytype

TYPE(mytype) :: a

a%ints=[1,2,3]
a%floats=[1,2,3,4,5]
a%chars=['a','b','c']

WRITE(*,*)a

END
```

The output is:

```
        1            2            3    1.000000        2.000000     
3.000000        4.000000        5.000000     abc
```

EDIT: As per suggestion by Jonathan Dursi:

In order to have an array where each element has a int, float and char element, you would do something like this:

```
TYPE mytype
  INTEGER   :: ints
  REAL      :: floats
  CHARACTER :: chars
ENDTYPE mytype

TYPE(mytype),DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: a

ALLOCATE(a(10))
```

You would then reference your elements as, e.g. `a(i)%ints`, `a(i)%floats`, `a(i)%chars`.
Related answer is given in [Allocate dynamic array with interdependent dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8557106/827297).

Comment: Just to add; IRO-bot's answer correctly gives you a derived type which contains arrays of ints, floats, and chars.  If you wanted an array of (type containing int + float + char), you'd define your type as above but without DIMENSIONS on the types - eg, a single int, float, and char - and then define eg. `TYPE(mytype), DIMENSION(10) :: a` or `TYPE(mytype), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:), :: a` and later `allocate(a(10))`.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thanks for the suggestion - I added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, guys. This is very helpful. So using derived types I can construct from the mainstream/default types my own type, the shape/dimension of which I can state in the definition or, even better, allocate it later based on how the program runs. Sweet.